# What is the best approach for team sign in after user sign in to the application?

Tags: node.js, authentication

I have an user sign in option on my app for that i'm using token based approach for the session handling. But now i want to create teams for each users and identify which team his currently logged in into. So what is the best approach for the team related session handling.

Answer (score 0):

Assign each user with a team. For example, Technical team have 6 users. so when a user detects then you can get his team.

Comment: That means we have to pass the current team the user logged in through the url right??

Comment: Cool...No problem You can define each user with a default team (that would be selected by user). And when he logged in then he can switch his team . when a user click on another team then you can save his current team in session/local-data/database/cookies.

Comment: So how to pass the data to the backend through the url right??

Comment: no......if your system is api based then you can send it through json or You can save his current team in cookie or you can save it in his local-storage.

Comment: ok got some idea but i have heard something called domain based approach do you have any idea about it?

Comment: domain based approach is related to wireless sensor networks.

Comment: No for the team management example for a team `food.team.com` and for another team `apple.team.com` like this

Comment: they are sub-domains.

Comment: example apple.team.com,hp.team.com,dell.team.com all are 3 different systems .

Comment: oh ok got some idea Thank you